# Tilemapping with SKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, path-finding

I'm fully aware that this place is for code snippets. However, I'm not too sure where too look for my particular problem.

I want to make a tile game, where the a.i use the A* pathfinding technique.

Now, there's plenty of information regarding the A* pathfinding, yet I'm struggling to decipher the setup for it to work.

Say I want to create a grid class for each grid square.

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface Grid : SKNode

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint gridPosition;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *gridName;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL walkable;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL visibility;

@end
```

Then a loop on their init to draw them in a pattern. What sort of name do I need to allocate to these grid squares? Like A1, A2, A3...B10,B11 etc? And also the reason as to why, for the A* implementation?

I'm more or less trying to think of this logically.. I.e, A.I is on square A2, needs to get to square C12, uses A* to determine path and finds around non-walkable paths?

It's a lot to take in so anyone who can give me a few pointers or things that will help me not debug for 24 hours would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is a question better suited for the Game Development community. Look at this answer http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46392/efficient-path-finding-on-2d-tile-based-multilevel-map

Comment: @sangony Thanks for the link, I'm sure I'll be better suited there